# link redirect to another page and specific tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this possible using jQuery/javascript?

In another page, I have a `<nav>` that are just tabs and shows only a specific content when you click a `tab-link`.

page1.html:

```
<nav class="subPageNav">
   <a href="#" id="A" class="tab-link">A</a>
   <a href="#" id="B" class="tab-link">B</a>
   <a href="#" id="C" class="tab-link">C</a>
   <a href="#" id="D" class="tab-link">D</a>
</nav>

<section id="A">
<!-- content -->
</section>

<section id="B">
<!-- content -->
</section>

and so on..
```

In a separate page, I have an `<a>` where I should be sent to the specific tab from another page.

page2.html

```
<a href="next.html#A">A</a>
```

The code I had isn't working as I wanted. How can I pull off this?

Comment: anchors `#` can be anchored in the same page, but not linked between separate documents

Comment: @parallaxis It seems it can - it works for me on my site

Comment: How can I perform this if it's on seperate pages?

Comment: @JBDouble05 with a full url to the seperate document it can work from page1 `href="/page2#anchor"` to open in a new tab add `<a href="next.html#A" target="_blank">A</a>`

Comment: Yes, that's what I was getting at @parallaxis.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that hides/shows the tab. Entering a page with an anchor will simply scroll to it - it will not simulate a click on that element.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the hash in the URL, find the corresponding element and then trigger a click:

```
$(function() {
  var activeTab = document.querySelector(location.hash);
  if (activeTab) {
    activeTab.click();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   var activeTab = window.location.hash;
   if (activeTab) {
      $( activeTab )[0].click();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked out for me. I added `id` to the `<a>` buttons.

page1.html

```
<a id="nav-a" href="page2.html">A</a>
<a id="nav-b" href="page2.html">B</a>
<a id="nav-c" href="page2.html">C</a>
<a id="nav-d" href="page2.html">D</a>
```

then create a javascript file with this

```
$(function() {

    $('a#nav-a').click(function(event) {
    localStorage.setItem("text", "nav-a");
    });

    $('a#nav-b').click(function(event) {
    localStorage.setItem("text", "nav-b");
    });

    /*and so on...*/

    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var pathSub = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.length)

    if(pathSub == "page2.html"){
        document.getElementById(localStorage.getItem('text')).click();
    }
})
```

and for the page2.html, I include the `id` the same as the `id` of the `<a>` elements.

```
<nav class="subPageNav">
   <a href="#" id="nav-a" class="tab-link">A</a>
   <a href="#" id="nav-b" class="tab-link">B</a>
   <a href="#" id="nav-c" class="tab-link">C</a>
   <a href="#" id="nav-d" class="tab-link">D</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use a partially full URL:

```
<a href="/next.html#A">A</a>
```

Try using this - all that changed is the `/` at the start.

Comment: This will simply scroll to the anchor, however it sounds like OP is relying on the *click* of the anchor to hide/show content.