# How to make a click on the corresponding tab when clicking a link on another page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There are two pages of one site. On one are links. On another tab menu. How can I make a click on the corresponding tab when clicking a link on another page?   I mean a menu like the one in the picture. I need when I click on one of the links to activate the desired tab on another page, the corresponding link. First link = first tab, second link = second tab, etc.
[image]

```js
    let tab = function() {
        let tabNav = document.querySelectorAll('.tabItem');
        let tabContent = document.querySelectorAll('.tabsContent');
        let tabName;


        tabNav.forEach((item, i) => {
            item.addEventListener('click', selectTabNav)
        });
        function selectTabNav(){
            tabNav.forEach((item, i) => {
                item.classList.remove('tabItem-active');
            });
            this.classList.add('tabItem-active');
            tabName = this.getAttribute('data-tab-name');
            selectTabContent(tabName);
        }

        function selectTabContent(tabName) {
         tabContent.forEach(item => {
         item.classList.contains(tabName) ? item.classList.add('tabsContent-active') : item.classList.remove('tabsContent-active');
     })
 }

};
tab();
```

```css
.tabsContent{
    display: none;
    width:150px;
    background-color: orange;
}
.tabsContent-active{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--//Page1//--> <br>

<a href="services-details.html" class="serviceBtn" id="btn1">Подробнее</a>
<a href="services-details.html" class="serviceBtn" id="btn2">Подробнее</a>
<a href="services-details.html" class="serviceBtn" id="btn3">Подробнее</a>

<br>
<!--//Page 2//-->  
<ul>
  <li class="tabItem tabItem-active" data-tab-name="tab-1">Tab1</li>
  <li class="tabItem" data-tab-name="tab-2">Tab2</li>
  <li class="tabItem" data-tab-name="tab-3">Tab3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="tabsContent tab-1 tabsContent-active">1</li>
  <li class="tabsContent tab-2">2</li>
  <li class="tabsContent tab-3">3</li>
</ul>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: What do you mean by tabs? Browser tabs? UI tabs?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @BSLabs Edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But I think what you want is to create three `<a> tags` which can link to corresponding tabs from another page **services-details.html**.

If I'm right then you need to provide a id to the `href attribute`:

```
<a href="services-details.html#id1" class="serviceBtn" id="btn1">Подробнее</a>
```

and then give the same id to the `li's or the div you are trying to link`:

```
<li class="tabsContent tab-1 tabsContent-active" id="id1">1</li>
```

This should link to the corresponding tabs.
If this is not what you were looking for then I apologize and kindly make yourself more clear.
Thanks.

**Edit:**
Since your question is much more understandable now, seems like your question is the duplicate of a question. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530242/13182598). Please take a look.

Comment: I need to activate a tab. When I click on the second link, I should automatically click on the second tab. When on the 3rd, then the 3rd tab.   Switching between tabs is done using a script, but I need to simulate a click on the desired tab while following the link. Hope I could explain. )

Comment: Kindly take a look at the link in the answer and see if it works for you.